# Fiery Blood damage taken by a Blood Draining Creature

Tags: spells, pathfinder-1e, monsters

**How does the spell Fiery Blood interact with a Blood Drain ability?**

> FIERY BLOOD
> School transmutation [fire]; Level druid/shaman 5,
> sorcerer/wizard 4
> Components V, S, M (pinch of sulfur)
> Casting Time 1 standard action
> Range touch
> Target one living creature
> Duration 2 rounds/level
> Saving Throw Will negates (harmless); SR no
> The blood of the target becomes fiery and burns with
> a hot, purifying flame. The target glows as brightly as a
> torch and acquires fast healing 4 for the duration of the
> spell. In addition, any opponent that successfully strikes
> the target with a piercing or slashing attack takes 1 hp fire
> damage for every die of damage inflicted on the target of
> the spell.
> Mythic: The target of the spell gains fire resistance 10.
> The fire damage that an opponent takes when it hits the
> target with a piercing or slashing weapon is increased by
> a number equal to your mythic tier.

I'm looking for advice from other GM/DMs, as I can't find any rules which elaborate on this specific situation. There are a handful of creatures which have various Blood Drain abilities,
such as a Stirge, Vampire, Blood Orchid, Mandragora Swarm, Bloodsuckle, Blood Golem, Gutslug, Pond Drinker, Leech Swarm, and likely even a Crimson Death's "Engulf" abiilty.

Using a stirge as an example, Blood Drain is obviously piercing so they'd take 1hp damage from just exposure from stabbing with their feeding tube.
If the stirge immediately disengages, which seems likely as it wouldn't want to ingest fiery blood, then I can see it just taking the 1hp... but if it was to drain 1 CON worth of blood, would it be reasonable to expect a 5hp (max) stirge to die from the attempt?

What is a reasonable amount of damage to take per CON point of Blood Drain when draining a creature with Fiery Blood?

Comment: This seems to be a homebrew balance question? I can't seem to find that spell anywhere in my search. Also, your question header should just be the title and should probably mention homebrew (if it is indeed so). I don't think it needs to be closed (as oppinion-based), but it does need some minor clarifications.

Comment: To me, the question reads "How *should* a GM adjudicate this spell under these conditions?" which seems pretty opinion-based. I might agree that a creature consuming Fiery Blood should take additional damage while another GM would argue that spells shouldn't do anything they don't say they do, and apply the damage normally. There doesn't seem to be a right answer. It *might* be able to be rewritten as a homebrew question, but it seems too specific to justify that approach. This feels like one for the forums.

Comment: Remember that being a valid question does not necessarily equate to it being a valid question *for this site*.

Comment: @Jason_c_o The spell is from Deep Magic a published supplement to PathFinder 1e by Kobold Press. So it is not a homebrew spell.

Comment: I'm going to leave this question closed as there are no rules in PathFinder that relate hp loss to Con loss. Which I believe is either a concession to keep the game from being too complex, or a blatant oversight on Paizo's part. I will have to homebrew the needed rules. Thanks for the feedback everyone.

Answer (score 3):

Strictly as written, it doesn't interact at all with blood drain. The fire damage only triggers in response to Slashing and Piercing damage specifically. Con damage is neither of these, so it doesn't trigger.

If you chose to houserule that Con damage from blood drain triggers the fire damage, you run into another problem with the Stirge: the fire damage from fiery blood is based on the dice of the incoming attack, and the Stirge's blood drain doesn't have any dice (it's a flat 1). You would also underestimate the damage since Con damage is more impactful than HP damage. (Not that I think the damage scales correctly in normal circumstances since it can't reflect any damage bonus, which are often significant on physical attacks)

If I was changing this to also affect Blood Drain, I would have it trigger for every 2 Con damage, the number it takes to reduce HP. Possibly more than once (based on the HP taken, I'd go for somewhere like 1 per 3-5 damage, matching the average values of d6 and d8), since it's a niche spell in a niche situation.

Answer (score 1):

Strictly as written, bloodsucking creatures are not affected in any special way by Fiery Blood unless their attacks deal slashing or piercing damage (and roll dice when they do). This is not very satisfying for the player that thought of a neat defense against bloodsuckers! As a niche situation and a niche spell, it would be good to reward the player with a worthwhile bit of damage for their clever approach.

*As far as damage in concerned:* A spellcaster that can cast this spell is already 7th or 9th level or higher. At this level, stirges should no longer be a significant threat, even in larger groups. So as a GM I would be more than happy to allow a spell of this level to counter them entirely. After all, a burning hands would do the same job just as well. However, I wouldn't want the spell to trivialize an encounter with relevant foes, like vampires or even mandragora. So the correct damage in response to a blood drain should be one that threatens stirges but not other, more powerful foes. I would peg that at about 2d6 fire damage (per blood drain attempt, not per CON damage). That way stirges will almost always get immolated by the attempt to drain blood, while vampires will only learn their lesson and avoid it in the future.